# How to fit all elements into React-Bootstrap cards with flexbox?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-bootstrap, card

I have this going in react bootstrap.  I have movie cards which consist of a picture, some text and a button.  I need all of the cards to be equal height but the data inside keeps overflowing.  It is built with bootstrap because it was a bootcamp project and I need to polish it up.  I am trying to use flexbox for the cards but am having trouble.
EDIT:
I want the cards to remain the same so the text can overflow but it needs to stay hidden and not show partial text.

[image: Overflowing text]

What I want (Notice how the text cuts off and there is no partial text showing)

[image]

```
<Card className="cardClass">
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
       <Card.Img  className="card-image" variant="top" src={movie.ImagePath} />
    </div>
   
    <Card.Body>
      <div className="card-text-body">
        <Card.Title>{movie.Title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>{movie.Genre.Name}</Card.Text>
        <Card.Text className='card-description'>{movie.Description}</Card.Text>
         <Link to={`/movies/${movie._id}`}>
          <Button className="movieCard-btn" variant="primary">View Movie</Button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>


.card {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}

.cardClass {
  
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.card-image{
    width:  100px;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-title {
    font-weight: 900;
}
.card-text-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
}
.card-description {
    font-size: 13px;
    
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-body {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.movieCard-btn {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
.btn .btn-primary {
    text-align: center!important;
}
.btn-primary {
    color: black;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    border-color: black;
}
.btn-primary:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    border-color: black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

Comment: the movie description text can vary and make other cards different sizes. I would recommend looking into flex grow:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow, like this the card will grow  based on the largest description.

Comment: I want the cards to remain the same size.  The text can overflow but it needs to stay hidden and not show partial text.

Comment: in that case use use overflow: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Comment: But then the text cuts off and partial text is shown. I posted a picture or what I am looking for.

Comment: You can only have one line because you have to use the white-space: no wrap property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches here:

**First**

Limit the description characters, something like:

```
let description = movie.description;    
if (description.length > 120) {
    description = description.substring(0, 120);
}
```

**Or**

- Card must be 100% height to fill remaining space.
- Your title set to flex-grow: 1, in order to push everything down below.
- Don't forget to set height on description box and also overflow: hidden;

  ```
  .card {
      margin-bottom: 4rem;
      background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
      height: 100%;
  }

  .card-title {
      font-weight: 900;
      flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .card-description {
      font-size: 13px;

      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100px;
  }
  ```

Comment: Pretty good but the bottom button overflows